# Azure SQL how to create a 2014 Adventure Works OLTP database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, oltp

We are not SQL experts but have an Azure SQL account and chose to load the AW "sample". We noticed that it was the LT version and we are trying to test the new Microsoft Power BI 2.0 and "believe" we need the FULL 2014 AW dataset and the OLTP version.

We have a 250 GB Azure SQL server instance.

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to test in the new Microsoft Power BI 2.0?

Comment: Test the ability to build Dashboards from SQL DBs

Answer (score 1):

Download the scripts package from https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550 and run it from SSMS connected to your Azure SQL DB. IIRC, there were a few issues/bugs about indexes and such. Look in the issues section of the download page for more or just search.

Comment: Thank you, any context on the "issues/bugs" and we are not experts in this?

Comment: As indicated above, look at the issues section in the same page. Just click on it and look for the advanced option and click on that. You can then add keyword filters like 2014 to see if the ones reported affect you.